# xargs sed cmd error xargs: gsed: No such file or directory

Tags: sed, xargs

I am trying to replace the below line in `myfiles.hcl` file

```
"-var-file=${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/variables/eu-west-2.tfvars",
```

with

```
"-var-file=${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/variables/eu-west-2.tfvars",
"-var-file=${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/variables/eu-west-2-prod.tfvars",
```

using xargs gsed cmd

```
 find . -name 'myfiles.hcl' | xargs grep -l 'prod' | xargs gsed -i 's|"-var-file=${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/variables/eu-west-2.tfvars",|"-var-file=${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/variables/eu-west-2.tfvars",'\\n' "-var-file=${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/variables/eu-west-2-prod.tfvars",|'
```

But I am getting an error `xargs: gsed: No such file or directory`

Comment: And do you have a `gsed` command on your system?

Answer (score 1):

You are probably on some non-GNU system like *BSD and your `sed` is written in a way that would not run on most `sed` flavours. So you can either install the GNU `sed` as `gsed` or you simply change the script to be compatible with your `sed`. I can see two GNU dependencies:

1. The `-i` option is supported by many `sed` versions, but require an argument for backup file extension (a good idea because you can mess up your system easily with bulk inplace editing). So replace it by `-i.bak`.
2. You use `\n` in the replacement, which is taken as a newline in GNU `sed`, but as the character `n` in most `sed` versions. The correct way is to use an actual newline preceeded by a blackslash.

Please allow me to give additional hints on your script:

- Instead of repeating the whole matching pattern in the replacement, you could use `&`:

  ```
  sed 's/long pattern/& added after the match/'
  ```
- Why do you leave the single quotes and do `'\\n'` instead of staying in the quotes and directly write `\n`?
- Instead of adding a line by replacing the matching line by itself along with the new line, simply use the `a`ppend command of `sed`:

  ```
  sed '/the line after which to append/a\
  the new line'
  ```
- In your special case where the new line is almost the same as the given line, it could avoid errors by typos to print the line and modify it:

  ```
  sed -i.bak '\|"-var-file=${get_parent_terragrunt_dir()}/variables/eu-west-2.tfvars"|{p;s/west-2/&-prod/;}'
  ```